# How do you refer to an instance of a class using a string entry

Tags: python, customtkinter

I am trying to create a login menu using OOP classes and customtkinter. I have created one admin instance to test, the name of the variable that stores this instance is the same as the instance's ID. I cannot figure out how to pass this string variable into the class's defined login function.

I have tried using the exec() function but so far it still won't work.

Could someone please look at my code and let me know where I am going wrong?

```
import customtkinter as ctk    

admin_list = []
admin_logins = {}

class Admin(User):

    def __init__(self, firstName, surname, phoneNum, ID, password):
        User.__init__(self, firstName, surname, phoneNum, ID)
        self.password = password
        self.loggedIn = False
        admin_logins[self.ID] = self.password
        admin_list.append(self.ID)

    def login(self, ID, password):
        if ID in admin_list:
            if admin_logins[ID] == password:
                if self.loggedIn == False:
                    print(f"Welcome {self.firstName}! You Are Logged In")
                    self.loggedIn = True
                else:
                    print("You are already logged in")
            else:
                print("Login Failed - Incorrect ID or Password")
                self.loggedIn = False
        else:
            print("Login Failed - Incorrect ID or Password")
            self.loggedIn = False

def drawLogin():

    un_entry = ctk.CTkEntry(main, placeholder_text="Admin ID", font=(font, 12))
    un_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="we",pady=0)
    pw_entry = ctk.CTkEntry(main, placeholder_text="Password", font=(font, 12), show="●") # ●
    pw_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="we")

    # Login Button

    def loginEvent():
        un = un_entry.get()
        pw = pw_entry.get()
        User.login(un, un, pw)


    login_button = ctk.CTkButton(main, text="Login", command=loginEvent)
    login_button.grid(column=1, row=3, pady=40)


A10211450 = Admin("Elliot", "Robot", "07785 124545", "A10211450", "password")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're throwing away the Admin user instance. You could easily save all admins during instance creation. OTOH, login can't be a instance method. It has to be at least a class or static method, or global method, e.g.:

```py
admins = {}


class Admin(User):

    def __init__(self, firstName, surname, phoneNum, ID, password):
        super().__init__(firstName, surname, phoneNum, ID)
        self.password = password
        self.loggedIn = False
        admins[self.ID] = self


def login(ID, password):
    user = None
    try:
        user = admins[ID]
        if user.password == password:
            if not user.loggedIn:
                print(f"Welcome {user.firstName}! You Are Logged In")
                user.loggedIn = True
            else:
                print("You are already logged in")
        else:
            # log out user if logged in and wrong password, remove if not needed
            user.loggedIn = False
    except KeyError:
        pass
    if not user or not user.loggedIn:
        print("Login Failed - Incorrect ID or Password")


def drawLogin():

    un_entry = ctk.CTkEntry(main, placeholder_text="Admin ID", font=(font, 12))
    un_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="we", pady=0)
    pw_entry = ctk.CTkEntry(main, placeholder_text="Password", font=(font, 12), show="●")
    pw_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="we")

    # Login Button

    def loginEvent():
        un = un_entry.get()
        pw = pw_entry.get()
        login(un, pw)

    login_button = ctk.CTkButton(main, text="Login", command=loginEvent)
    login_button.grid(column=1, row=3, pady=40)


A10211450 = Admin("Elliot", "Robot", "07785 124545", "A10211450", "password")
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you for the explanation! :)

Comment: @ElTC Would you mind upvote the answer or make it the accepted answer? Thanks.